# Remove Backslash between 2 characters from string

Tags: php, regex, backslash

I need to replaces backslashes only between 2 characters, except quotes (")

So if I have this STRING:

```
When I look at you, I\understand why I live //replace
When I look at you, I "\understand why I live // No replace
When I look at you, I"\understand why I live // No replace
Sword art online\Мастера меча онлайн opening //replace Sword art online Мастера меча онлайн opening
```

This is for a json string, but if I use stripslashes, all backslases will removed. I only need to remove if string no have " quotes.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `preg_replace('~\b\\\b~', '', $str)`

Comment: `addslashes(stripslashes($string));`

Comment: What if you capture all ` \\ ` that follow a `"`, and also match all the remaining ` \\ ` in the string, then replace all those captured ` "...\\ ` (such as in [this](https://regex101.com/r/pO5jU4/1) example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$text = preg_replace('~"[^"]*"\K|\\\\~', '', $text);
```

or this one:

```
$text = preg_replace('~"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\\\\~', '', $text);
```

The two patterns consumes characters enclosed between quotes.
The first pattern uses `\K` to remove all characters matched on the left from the match result. The second forces the pattern to fail (with `(*F)`) and to not retry characters between quotes (with `(*SKIP)`).

Note that a literal backslash must be written `\\\\` in the pattern string. (the backslash is escaped once for the string and once for the regex engine).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$strings = array(
    'When I look at you, I\understand why I live',
    'When I look at you, I "\understand why I live',
    'When I look at you, I"\understand why I live',
    'Sword art online\Мастера меча онлайн opening'
);

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $str = addslashes(stripslashes($string));
    var_dump($str);
}
```

Comment: Awesome. glad I could help. Let me know if you need anything else.